# How can I disable Switch Button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below jquery for switch.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Custom-On-Off-Toggle-Switch-Plugin-For-jQuery-on-off-switch-js/
Documentation link
(http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=on-off-switch)

This js convert checkbox to switches.

But there is no option to disable switch using jQuery.

Can anyone help me how can I get this done.

Thanks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: You can have a try with pointer-events: none; style

Comment: Yes that's works but is there any way to do from onOffSwitch function itself?

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way could be:

The file "on-off-switch.js" contains a function:

```
listenToClickEvent : function(){
    if (disabled) {
      return
    }
}
```

and set the disabled flag elsewhere.
I would invest some time to look for a better solution (e.g. disable per css)